# Could a foreign government arrest a US citizen for whatever it wants to?

Tags: united-states

I was thinking about the idea of universal jurisdiction. It was said that countries can prosecute people who commit war crimes regardless of their nationality.

A famous person says something critical of that government or its supported policies. In this hypothetical case, could that government order him to be sent there?

There was a [Hong Kong security law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/55981/can-i-a-random-person-in-the-world-be-prosecuted-under-the-new-hong-kong-secur) that could apply to everybody on the planet.

That person did not violate any US laws. But they violated the law of a country that doesn't allow free speech or something along those lines.

If they wanted to arrest anybody (not necessarily who I used previously for the example), what means would they have at their disposal? Could they send in secret agents to transport the "criminal"? Sign an extradition agreement?

Comment: Are you asking if a foreign government can arrest a US citizen while they are in the US (Wikipedia's page on [US extradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extradition_law_in_the_United_States) law should answer that pretty well), or are you asking if a foreign government can arrest a US citizen while they are in that other country (which seems to be trivially 'yes' since a government can basically do anything if they don't worry about any consequences).

Comment: You may want to consider the situations of Michael Spavor and Michael Kovrig. Link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Spavor   Link:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Kovrig

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

If you go where that foreign country can get their hands on you, they can do that. Examples include the Israeli capture of [Eichmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Eichmann) in Argentina and the US prison camp in [Guantanamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guantanamo_Bay_detention_camp).

This statement, which might sound alarming to you, is qualified by a few factors.

- States usually do not sign extradition treaties which would allow extradition for acts which are *not a crime* in the extraditing country. There is generally an extradition hearing in court. A [Chinese businesswoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meng_Wanzhou) went to Canada and was arrested there on an US request. The hearings are ongoing.
- Most states have signed the [Vienna Convention on Consular Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Consular_Relations), which allows diplomats to visit foreign nationals detained abroad.
- The Eichmann case is an extreme example. If those Mossad agents had been captured by Argentina, they might have gone to prison themselves.

Comment: To add to the Eichmann qualification. Consider the case of Duane "Dog the Bounty Hunter" Chapman who attempted to lawfully enforce a bail warrant under U.S. law by arresting Andrew Luster, a convicted criminal, who had fled to Mexico during his U.S. trial for rape in 2003 and was subsequently convicted *in abstentia*. The problem was that bounty hunting is illegal in Mexico so Chapman was arrested by the Mexican government who charged Chapman with kidnapping and jailed him.

Comment: @RainWillow, Chapman didn't lawfully try to enforce a warrant because US warrants are no good in Mexico. But the case is a good example how international extradition can become a political pawn.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidnapping_of_Sidney_Jaffe .  The kidnappers got their victim into the US, and the courts in Florida then proceeded against the fugitive.